# How to iteratively add and remove images to an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a simple webpage with a changing background image, but am uncertain how to achieve the desired effect.

Within my  tag I've created an array of images (filepaths, to be more precise). I've retrieved the DOM element by id. And I've written a for loop that should iterate over the aforementioned array. The loop should:

- 1 - create a new "img" element
- 2 - set its src to the current array item (which, again, is a filepath)
- 3 - append this newly created image to the retrieved DOM element
- 4 - then, at the completion of this iteration, the 'img' element should be removed

The below is the JS code embedded in the HTML doc...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {

        var image_array= [
        "static/arch.jpg",
        "static/pasture.jpg",
        "static/starry_night.jpg",
        "static/arturo.jpg",
        "static/desert.jpg",
        "static/jedi.jpg",
        "static/kylo.jpg",
        "static/trooper.jpg"
        ]

    var background = document.getElementById('cur_background');

        for (var i = 0, j = image_array.length; i < j; i++) {
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = image_array[i]; 
            background.appendChild(img);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('img').remove();
                }, 5000);
        }

    });
```

The HTML element where the images will appear is written below...

```
    <div class="middle">
        <ul class="middle_background">
            <li id= "cur_background"></li>
            <!-- <li id="1"><img src="static/arch.jpg"></li>
            <li id="2"><img src="static/pasture.jpg"></li>
            <li id="3"><img src="static/starry_night.jpg"></li>
            <li id="4"><img src="static/arturo.jpg"></li>
            <li id="5"><img src="static/desert.jpg"></li>
            <li id="6"><img src="static/jedi.jpg"></li>
            <li id="7"><img src="static/kylo.jpg"></li>
            <li id="8"><img src="static/trooper.jpg"></li> -->
        </ul>
        <h2>And so the story begins...</h2>
    </div>
```

**What I expect to happen:**

The loop iterates over the image array, creates a temporary 'img' element in which it will appear, then removes the 'img' element when it reaches the end of that particular loop iteration.

**What actually happens:**

All the images load at once, appear in list format within the correct DOM element ('cur-background'), and then disappear en mass when the setTimeout interval activates.

Comment: $('img').remove(); is selecting all the images.... not the current one. If you want to remove them all, then you are doing it 9 times.

Comment: A small loop like yours will take only milliseconds (if that) to complete. So, in a **very** short period of time, you've created an image, appended it to the document and set it up so that 5 seconds later it will be removed. Since the loop runs so quickly, the 5 second counter doesn't run consecutively, it is essentially running concurrently. But, it's actually still unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please add the corresponding HTML so that we can replicate your issue.

Comment: "Since the loop runs so quickly, the 5 second counter doesn't run consecutively, it is essentially running concurrently..." I'd assumed the setTimeout would apply to each element of the loop...but because of how quickly the computer processes the other commands the setTimeout is left hanging with a long delay? Correct?     --------  and to clarify what my goal is: I'd like my webpage to display a new background image every five seconds or so.

Comment: `$('img')` is not applying to "each element".  It is a selector, selecting all images, as already stated.  Just because you have a variable named `img` doesn't mean that string is going to do something different.

Comment: Short solution, change `var img` to `let img` and take the quotes off of the `$('img')` in the timeout

Comment: So it seems like my main problem is that I'm underestimating the speed of the computer. If my loop were to run step by step, very slowly, it would work. However, because all 9 "img" elements are created and embedded before the first instance of setTimeout kicks in (at 5 seconds) all 9 "img" elements are removed by this function.   Is this thinking correct?

Comment: Yes, fixing the issue with the selector selecting all the images will not address the issue that Scott pointed out.

Comment: Taplar - I've made the changes but continue to have the same results. All 9 images load in bulk, then disappear at the 5 second mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $background = $('#cur_background');

function loopBackgroundImages ( nextIndex ) {
  // create an image tag
  var $img = $('<img>').attr('src', image_array[nextIndex]);

  // append it to the background
  $background.append($img);

  setTimeout(function(){
    // after 5 seconds, remove the image and iterate to the next loop
    // you can use modulus (%) to cause the index to wrap back to 0
    $img.remove();
    loopBackgroundImages( ++nextIndex % image_array.length );
  }, 5000);
}

// start the loop at index 0
loopBackgroundImages(0);
```

Comment: And it works! Also, clever addition to recycle the loop using modulus so that the images continue to cycle and don't stop after just one full iteration. I'm certain there's a more efficient way to accomplish this (perhaps using CSS show/hide attributes which could be linked to JS) but completion versus perfection is a great start. This was my first question on StackOverflow! Thanks for the quick and responsive feedback to all. Much appreciated Taplar.